# How to delete image from Firebase storage by url?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How to delete image from Firebase storage by url?
When I remove item(category) from collection, image remains in storage.

Interface category:

```
    export interface ICategory {
        readonly id     : string
        name            : string
        image           : string 
    }
```

Function for remove

```
    export const removeCategoryFB = (id: string, setCategories: any) => {
      firestore()
        .collection("categories")
        .doc(id)
        .delete()
        .then(() => {
          getCategoriesFB(setCategories);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          alert(err);
        });
    };
```

Comment: You have to give reference to the database at the place of `firestore()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolve this problem with

```
refFromURL(URL)
```

Example code

```
  firestore()
    .collection('categories')
    .doc(id)
    .get()
    .then((snapshot) => {
      storage()
        .refFromURL(snapshot.data().image.url)
        .delete()
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get storage reference then you will give file storage path to delete the file.

```
deleteChatFiles(filePath) {
    const spaceRef = firebase
      .storage()
      .ref()
      .child(filePath);
    spaceRef.delete();
  } 

this.deleteFile('files/1579283129986-vMglgpHwT6c06RSmAiuYP6Hk2sz1.png');
```